# Visual studio cordova plugin inclusion conditional to build configuration

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

I have a cordova project from Visual Studio 2015 for an hybrid app.

Anyone knows how I could add a plugin but only for a debug build configuration?
Or even, some kind of debug switch to be on only on debug.

Thanks.